# In python co-routine, two successive socket.recv() causes BlockingIOError

Tags: python, sockets, nonblocking, recv

I have a piece of python code to practice python co-routines. 
As explained by [A. Jesse Jiryu Davis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idLtMISlgy8).

- Firstly, I define a co-routine named '**get**' to get the content of some
  URL.
- Then I define a **Task** class to iterate the co-routine to completion.
- Then I create one **Task** object which open one URL.

If I put two successive socket.recv() method in the co-routine, I got the error message:
*'A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately'*  in the second **chunk = s.recv(1000)** line.

- But if I change all the **yield** to time.sleep(1) and directly call
  get() in the global context, the two successive s.recv(1000) will
  cause no errors. Even more successive s.recv(1000) is OK.

After several days searching and reading python documents, I still have no idea why this is happening. I must missed some 'python Gotchas', do I?

I'm using python 3.6 to test. The code is as following and I have deleted all the irrelevant code to make the following code precise and relevant to the topic:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import socket
import select
import time

selectors_read = []
selectors_write = []

class Task:
    def __init__(self, gen):
        self.gen = gen
        self.step()

    def step(self):
        try:
            next(self.gen)
        except StopIteration:
            return

def get():
    s = socket.socket()
    selectors_write.append(s.fileno())
    s.setblocking(False)
    try:
        s.connect(('www.baidu.com', 80))
    except:
        pass

    yield
    selectors_write.remove(s.fileno())

    print('[CO-ROUTINE] ', 'Send')
    selectors_read.append(s.fileno())
    s.send('GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode())

    yield

    while True:
        chunk = s.recv(1000)
        chunk = s.recv(1000)
        if chunk:
            print('[CO-ROUTINE] received')
        else:
            selectors_read.remove(s.fileno())
            break
        # yield


task_temp = Task(get())

while True:
    for filenums in select.select(selectors_read, selectors_write, []):
        for fd in filenums:
            task_temp.step()
```